# Reinterpret_cast use in C++

Tags: c++, fftw, reinterpret-cast

Just a simple question,having this:

```
fftw_complex *H_cast;
H_cast = (fftw_complex*) fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex)*M*N);
```

what is the difference between:

```
H_cast=  reinterpret_cast<fftw_complex*> (H);
```

and

```
H_cast= reinterpret_cast<fftw_complex*> (&H);
```

Thanks so much in advance

Antonio

Comment: If you want to ask the difference between two statements, you might want to give us two different statements?

Comment: sorry, a tip error, now is correct!

Comment: Edited to change the first option into what the OP probably intended.

Comment: One of the two has an ampersand, the other doesn't. Can you fix that?

Comment: My question is about the difference of having the ampersand or not, because it gives me an error during the execution of the programm in different places of a loop depending on that ampersand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Answer to current question**

The difference is that they do two completely different things!

*Note: you do not tell us what `H` is, so it's impossible to answer the question with confidence. But general principles apply.*

For the first case to be sensible code, `H` should be a pointer (typed as `void*` possibly?) to a `fftw_complex` instance. You would do this to tell the compiler that `H` is really a `fftw_complex*`, so you can then use it.

For the second case to be sensible code, `H` should be an instance of a class with a memory layout identical to that of class `fftw_complex`. I can't think of a compelling reason to put yourself in this situation, it is very unnatural. Based on this, and since you don't give us information regarding `H`, I think it's almost certainly a bug.

**Original answer**

The main difference is that in the second case you can search your source code for `reinterpret_cast` (and hopefully ensure that every use is clearly documented and a necessary evil).

However, if you are casting from `void*` to another pointer type (is this the case here?) then it's preferable to use `static_cast` instead (which can also be easily searched for).

Comment: H is     double* pointer, so, regarding your answer I think the suitable sentence must be the first one, but I am still receiving an error in execution time which is very likely produced because of this conversion, becasue a infraction is produced trying to read a place of memory which is not allowed.

Answer (score 1):

```
H_cast=  reinterpret_cast<fftw_complex*> (H);
```

This converts the pointer-ish type inside H (or the integer itself, if H is an integer type) and tells the compiler "this is a pointer. Stop thinking whatever it was, it's a pointer now". H is used as something where you had stored a pointer-like address.

```
H_cast= reinterpret_cast<fftw_complex*> (&H);
```

This converts the address of H (which is a pointer to whatever type H is) into a pointer to "fftw_complex". Modifying the contents of H_cast will now change H itself.

You'll want the second if H is not a pointer and usually the first if it is. There are use cases for the other way around but they're uncommon and ugly (especially reinterpreting an int or - god forbid - a double as a pointer).

Answer (score 0):

Pointer casts are always executed as a reinterpret_cast, so when casting from or to a void * there's no difference between a c-style cast, a static_cast or a reinterpret_cast.

Reinterpret_casts are usually reserved for the ugliest of locations where c-style casts and static_casts are used for innocuous casts. You basically use reinterpret_cast to tag some code as really-ugly:

```
float f = 3.1415f;
int x = *reinterpret_cast<int *>(&f);
```

That way, these ugly unsafe casts are searchable/greppable.

Comment: That depends on the type of pointer. There can - and often will be - a difference in result between a `static_cast` and a `reinterpret_cast` between pointers to class types.

Comment: Thanks - updated the comment to only say something about void pointers.

Comment: -1: C-style casts are if possible even worse than reinterpret_cast, don't encourage them...

Comment: I'm not encouraging c-style casts. I'm discouraging reinterpret_casts.

Comment: You literally say C-style casts are used for innocuous casts. C style casts are even more unclear and can even fall back into a reinterpret_cast.